Continuity of the function defined in the covering game paragraph (Jech, 1978)
In his book "Set theory" (1978), Jech presents the covering game to prove that, assuming AD, every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable. I can't understand a step in his proof: why the function $f$ defined mapping every $b$ played by II in an $a\in\mathbb{R}$  is continuous?  

In fact it's 1-Lipschitz: since $\sigma*b$ is the result of playing $\sigma$ against $b$, the value of $a_n$ is determined by the initial segment $\langle b_1,...,b_{n-1}\rangle$.

Thanks! I completely missed that. Your answer really helped!
